# Is there an output stream class for IOS I could use to print class data like qDebug in QT?

Tags: ios, stream-operators

In QT to many classes have stream << operators to print useful information about class members.
For example I can print QImage or QRect size like this:

```
QImage image(500, 100, QImage::Format_RGBA8888_Premultiplied);
qDebug() << "image: " << image;
```

output: image:  QImage(QSize(500, 100) )

```
QRect rect(3, 4, 100, 50);
qDebug() << "rect: " << rect;
```

output: rect:  QRect(3,4 100x50)

I find this pretty useful as you don't have to type every single class member to print it.

I am new to IOS coding. Is there any simple way to to the same thing for basic classes like CGRect, that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use standard library:

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(view.rect));
```

or try better [solution](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack) - is DDLog library, it can turn all logs output for example for release build, in this case use:

```
DDLogInfo(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(view.rect));
```

or

```
DDLogWarn(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(view.rect));
```

images to can be printed:

```
DDLogWarn(@"%@", image);
```